Form post to blank target on iOS not working
I'm trying to integrate a link to a webmail in my application with a form post to an external site that passes the username and password. My approach works on Android and on desktop browsers (including Safari). But it does not work on iOS. There are probably some restrictions I'm unaware of.
I have something like this in my site:
<form name="webmailPostLoginForm" method="post" action="https://mywebmail.com/?login" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" id="webmailPostLoginEmail" name="Email" />
    <input type="hidden" id="webmailPostLoginPassword" name="Password" />
</form>

I then use javascript to set the input values at runtime when the user wants to open the webmail and submit the form with javascript like so:
document.webmailPostLoginForm.submit();

Both sites use https. That mean I can rule out an issue with mixed content.
P.S: We are both owner of the webmail hosting and the website with the link and both sites are running on the same server. Maybe we need to add some headers on the webmail site?
